# At What Value of Column1 Is Column2 Minimum in A Data Frame in R

Tags: r

I have a `data frame` with two columns, I want to know at what value of column1 is column2 minimum.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(
  x1 = 1:10,
  x2 = rnorm(10)
)
x
```

| x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.6264538 |
| 2 | 0.1836433 |
| 3 | -0.8356286 |
| 4 | 1.5952808 |
| 5 | 0.3295078 |
| 6 | -0.8204684 |
| 7 | 0.4874291 |
| 8 | 0.7383247 |
| 9 | 0.5757814 |
| 10 | -0.3053884 |

I know that `column2` is minimum with:

```
min(x$x2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can keep the data.frame

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  filter(x2 == min(x2))

  x1         x2
1  3 -0,8356286
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
x$x1[which.min(x$x2)]
#[1] 3
```

Or

```
x$x1[x$x2 == min(x$x2)]
```

The difference between the two is that if there are multiple minimum values in `x2` `which.min` would always return only 1 value of `x1` (the first one) whereas `x$x1[x$x2 == min(x$x2)]` would return all of them.

If you want to keep all the columns of minimum row -

```
x[which.min(x$x2), ]

#  x1    x2
#3  3 -0.84
```